# Error when I try to install VMware 2.0.2 on my PC with 64-bit Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, vmware, installer

I need to install VMware in my PC, to install Linux on 64-bit Windows 7 host.

The problem is that when I double click the .exe, the error `Setup can not continue, Microsoft Runtime DLL. The installer failed to complete the installation` happens. The installer works on another PC with Windows XP (32 bits), so I think it does not work in 64-bit Windows 7.

Suggestions?

Comment: Vmware server 2.0.2

Answer (score 2):

VMware Server is obsolete, as per [their web site](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/overview.html), and this is probably the reason for it not to work in Windows 7. Try using [VMware Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player) or [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org).

Comment: I'd use VMWare Player. VirtualBox is a mess.

Answer (score 1):

Have seen this in a  number of cases and it seemed to relate to C++

Make sure you have the latest C++ Redistributable. 2008 version worked for me but that was a year ago I removed all other C++ insatlls on the system and rebooted. After doing this, I was able to install VMware Server just fine.

VMware Player is also a good route as noted by @Renan Birck Pinheiro